# How to read http POST request payload data in WSO2 ESB

Tags: java, web-services, wso2, wso2-esb

I am new to wso2 esb. I know how to read http url parameters. I have requirment that my proxy will receive http POST request with payload data in it. I want to know how to read that POST payload data in proxy.?

Comment: What do you want to do with the payload?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I am voting to close this question because is so abroad. You sould post relevant code for proving, at least, how far did you try...

Comment: @Bhathiya Input xml data is being sent via http POST request in payload from client. So, I want to read that data in wso2 esb. u got it..?

Comment: I understand that part. My question is what are you going to do after reading it. I'm asking that because the way you read can differ depending on what you are going to do with it.

Comment: @Bhathiya I will wrap that payload xml inside soap body using payloadFactory mediator, then send it to endpoint. Please tell me the answer

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to do a REST to SOAP transformation you don't need to read the message body. Here is a sample Synapse configuration.

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="TestAPI" context="/test">
   <resource methods="POST GET">
      <inSequence>
         <property name="SOAPAction" value="" scope="transport"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://demo8290629.mockable.io/test" format="soap11"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

You can call it like this.

```
curl -H "Content-Type:application/xml" -d '<ns:operationRequest xmlns:ns="http://demo8290629.mockable.io/service/1">testing</ns:operationRequest>' http://172.17.0.1:8280/test
```

However, if you want to read the message to a property, you can do it like this.

```
<property name="payload" expression="$body"/>
```